# How to setup vimscript command to call a function?

Tags: vim

So I want to be able to type something like:

*:hello*

in vim normal mode and then have it echo out 'hello sir'.

I made the below vimscript into a plugin, and I get the error:

*Not an editor command*

What am I doing wrong?

**vimscript**

```
if exists("g:hello_world") || &cp || v:version < 700 
  finish
endif
let g:hello_world=1 " your version number
let s:keepcpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

fun! s:hellosir()
  echo 'hello sir'
endfun

command hello call hellosir()
```

Comment: I wrote a mini "tutorial" on SU on vim scripts, functions and stuff: https://superuser.com/a/147233/13611

Answer (score 11):

steffen's answer is correct, but here is an example with an argument:

```
" a highlight color must be set up for the function to work
highlight blue ctermbg=blue guibg=blue

function! Highlight(text)
    :execute "match blue /" . a:text . "/"
endfunction

:command! -nargs=1 Highlight :call Highlight(<q-args>)
```

To run it and highlight all occurrences of a regex:

```
:Highlight foobar
```

Note that I try not to abbreviate commands/functions in .vimrc. Save abbreviations for when you're typing on the command line.

Answer (score 9):

Define your function (note the uppercase letter for user-defined functions):

```
:fun! Hellosir()
:    echo 'hello sir'
:endfun
```

Now call it:

```
:call Hellosir()
```

> `hello sir`

It is also possible to define your own ex command:

```
:command Hello :call Hellosir()
:Hello
```

> `hello sir`

**EDIT**

You can combine both: Make the function script-local and access it with your (global) ex command:

```
fun! s:hellosir()
  echo 'hello sir'
endfun
command Hello call s:hellosir()
```

Comment: Using a script local function is perfectly fine (actually preferred in this case). Using the `command Hello call s:hellosir()`. Now the command does need to be capitalized.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong relates with this line:

```
command hello call hellosir()
```

First, from `:h user-cmd-ambiguous`

> All user defined commands must start with an uppercase letter, to avoid
>   confusion with builtin commands. Exceptions are these builtin commands:
>
> - `:Next`
> - `:X`
>
> They cannot be used for a user defined command. [...]

Second, that you have to call your function with the `s:` prefix in that command.